# JS regex return string from url

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following URL structure:

```
https://api.bestschool.com/student/1102003120009/tests/json
```

I want to cut the student ID from the URL. So far I've came up with this:

```
/(student\/.*[^\/]*)/
```

which returns

> student/1102003120009/tests/json

I only want the ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex `(student\/.*[^\/]*)` matches and captures into Group 1 a literal sequence `student/`, then matches any characters other than a newline, 0 or more occurrences (`.*`) - that can match the whole line at once! - and then 0 or more characters other than `/`. It does not work because of `.*`. Also, a capturing group should be moved to the `[^\/]*` pattern.

You can use the following regex and grab Group 1 value:

```
student\/([^\/]*)
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hH6yI8/1)

The regex matches `student/` literally, and then matches and *captures* into Group 1 zero or more symbols other than `/`.

Alternatively, if you want to avoid using capturing, and assuming that the ID is always numeric and is followed by `/tests/`, you can use the following regex:

```
\d+(?=\/tests\/)
```

The `\d+` matches 1 or more digits, and `(?=\/tests\/)` checks if right after the digits there is a `/tests/` character sequence.

```js
var re = /student\/([^\/]*)/; 
var str = 'https://api.bestschool.com/student/1102003120009/tests/json';
var m = str.match(re);
if (m !== null) {
   document.getElementById("r").innerHTML = "First method&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;: " + m[1] + "<br/>";
}
var m2 = str.match(/\d+(?=\/tests\/)/);
if (m2 !== null) {
    document.getElementById("r").innerHTML += "Second method: " + m2;
}
```

```html
<div id="r"/>
```

Comment: I must ask, why is it adding it to array? Can't it retrieve only the ID? there is only one thing between "student/" and "/test"

Comment: It all depends on the context the ID appears in. If you need it to be right between `student/` and `/test`, you need to use a capturing group with `/sudent\/([^\/]*)\/test/` - and the captured value is inside the `m[1]`. See [`RegExp#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) reference. If you just need to get the *numeric* value before `/test`, you can get the match itself with `str.match(/\d+(?=\/test)/)`. As you see, everything depends on what part of the string we can use as context (=known details we can use a literal in the regex).

Comment: Is it possible to add a condition to the regex? "student/" sometimes can be "studentid/" , i want to cover both cases with same regex - possible?

Comment: Yes, possible. Use `\w*` that matches 0 or more alphanumeric symbols: `var re = /student\w*\/([^\/]*)/; `

Comment: I'm not quite how to do this, all my attempts failed

Comment: No idea what you attempted, but what I suggested above [works well](http://jsfiddle.net/30qwy10o/).